# How to perform a calculation on a row basis and SUM on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a situtaion where I have data in two columns in a table, which need to be multiplied on a row basis. Then each value from the multiplication has to be added to provide a net result

I tried this but it does not work

```
  public function getCampaignStats($item)
    {
        $query = CampaignStats::where('item',$item);
        foreach($query as $q) {
            $q->p_c;
            $q->caa;
            dd($q->p_c);
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

I get this exception when i try to do this

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

Is there a better way to do this foreach loop in laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can use **raw queries** for such a case and do the math within your query. Have a look at the docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-exists-clauses